# INotifyPropertyChanged for Count property in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

I have a textbox which is bound to an `Int` property in my viewmodel which gets a count of an `ObservableCollection`. Here is my Xaml binding:

```
Text="{Binding ArticleCount, Mode=OneWay}"
```

And my int property:

```
 private Int32 _ArticleCount;
    public int ArticleCount
    {
        get
        {                
            if (this.ModelviewArticleObservableList == null)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                return this.ModelviewArticleObservableList.Count;                  
            }               
        } 
    }
```

This works fine on application initialisation and I get the `ObservableCollection` count in my UI `TextBox`. However there are methods that then change the `ObservableCollection` and therefore the count changes. I need a Property Changed event to notify the when the count has changed but I'm not sure on how to do this? Here is my `ObservableCollection` property:

```
 private ObservableCollection<viewArticle> _ModelviewArticleObservableList = new ObservableCollection<viewArticle>();
    public ObservableCollection<viewArticle> ModelviewArticleObservableList
    {
        get { return _ModelviewArticleObservableList; }
        set
        {
            _ModelviewArticleObservableList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ModelviewArticleObservableList");                
        }
    }
```

I currently have a normal implementation of INPC:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Comment: You can subscribe to the `CollectionChanged` event of the `ObservableCollection<T>` and call `OnPropertyChanged("ArticleCount")` from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to raise the `PropertyChanged` event every time the number of elements in the collections changes. A good way is to subscribe to the [`CollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event of the `ObservableCollection`.

```
private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // you could examine e to check if there is an actual change in the count first
    OnPropertyChanged("ArticleCount");
}
```

Additionally there is the case that the collection itself is set to `null` or a different value, in which case your `ArticleCount` property should change too. You also have to remove your `CollectionChanged` event handler from the old collection and add it to the new one.

```
public ObservableCollection<viewArticle> ModelviewArticleObservableList
{
    get { return _ModelviewArticleObservableList; }
    set
    {
        if (_ModelviewArticleObservableList != null)
        {
            _ModelviewArticleObservableList.CollectionChanged -= OnCollectionChanged;
        }

        _ModelviewArticleObservableList = value;

        if (_ModelviewArticleObservableList != null)
        {
            _ModelviewArticleObservableList.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
        }

        OnPropertyChanged("ModelviewArticleObservableList");
        OnPropertyChanged("ArticleCount");
    }
}
```

Comment: I see what you're saying Dirk. My issue is that the setter for my ObservableCollection is never hit as it's just reading the values in. If I call the collectionChanged event in the getter of the ObservableCollection it's being called over & over for each record added...

Comment: @Hardgraf If you don't need the setter then simply remove it and subscribe to the `CollectionChanged` event in the constructor. And I don't understand your second point. Why would you want to raise events in a getter?

Comment: No, I didn't want to add events to the getter. Need to remind myself that it's a constructor of the ViewModel not the View! Still getting memory issues though as the event is fired on every count so need to figure that out...

Answer (score 4):

Is ModelviewArticleObservableList a publicly visible property of your ViewModel?

If so, you can bind your TextBox directly to it's Count property.

```
Text="{Binding Path=ModelviewArticleObservableList.Count}"
```

You need the "Path=" as you're not binding to a direct property. The "Mode=OneWay" is unnecessary.

ObservableCollection implements INotifyPropertyChanged, and the Count property will be notified for each update to the collection.

By the way, why are you using a TextBox rather than TextBlock for a value that can't be edited in the UI?

Comment: I wasn't able to to bind explicitly to the count of the ObservableCollection as there were over 7000  records in the collection & was facing memory issues.

Comment: TextBox can be a good idea for values that can't be edited if you want to allow the user to mark the value and copy it to clipboard.