# Binding to first N items in an ObservableCollection on a ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, observablecollection

I have an `ObservableCollection<T>` in my application that can hold numerous items.  Specifically, this is summary information from a potentially extensive logger.  What I'd like to do is bind strictly the top 3 items of this collection to WPF `ListView`.

Is there XAML syntax, or a simple enough way to create a secondary property in my VM, to always return the top 3 items in the collection as well as update any changes to the collection as a normal `ObservableCollection<T>` would if you were interacting with a complete list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You could roll-out your own `ObservableCollection<T>` with a property returning top items.**

Here's an example,

Code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MyCollection Collection { get; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Collection = new MyCollection();

            DataContext = Collection;
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Collection.Add(Collection.Count);
        }
    }

    public sealed class MyCollection : ObservableCollection<int>
    {
        public MyCollection()
        {
            CollectionChanged += MyCollection_CollectionChanged;
        }

        private void MyCollection_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {   // to notify XAML-side binding
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(TopItems)));
        }

        public IEnumerable<int> TopItems => this.Take(3);
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="525"
        Height="350"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MyCollection}"
        mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Click="button_Click" Content="Button" />
        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
        <ListBox Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding TopItems}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Yes, but if the `ObservableCollection<T>` has a new item added to the top of the list, will this automatically update the collection I'm using in my list view?  The point of this is that I want to have a region that is showing dynamic log details.  Once something is pushed onto the log, it needs to appear at the top of the list.  I don't think this will work this way.

Comment: you need to do this, then also listen for `CollectionChanged` event and call `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TopItems))`.  then your view will stay in sync.

Comment: @RLH yes, changes will be reflected, updated my answer with a better example.

Comment: aaa you were faster, I started an answer but I can see it's no longer needed as you've put everything need in yours :) +1 for you when I get my voting ability back :)

Comment: I'd actually considered this approach.  I asked this question because I hoped that there was possibly special XAML syntax that would take just the top N.  Thanks.  I'll give you the answer mark.

Answer (score 3):

You want to check this:
[INotifyPropertyChanged for Count property in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24180519/7708157)

Simply listen on `CollectionChanged` of your ObservableCollection and there notify your viewmodel about changing your property holding only first 3 items (which can be implemented simply as

```
public MyTopItems
{
    get
    {
        return myCollection.Take(3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use a paged list

```
return myCollection.Skip(10).Take(3);
```