# How can I bind top N items of an ObservableCollection to ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I want to bind top N items of an ObservableCollection to ItemsControl.

I've tried this solution:
[Binding to first N items in an ObservableCollection on a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43264213/binding-to-first-n-items-in-an-observablecollection-on-a-listview/43264457#43264457)

Here is my code:
XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="IC" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="#cecece" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Background="Transparent" >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ABC}"></TextBlock>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel></VirtualizingStackPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            IC.ItemsSource = CM.TopCollection;
        }
        CollectionModel CM = new CollectionModel();
        public class TestModel {
            public string ABC { get; set; }
        }
        public class CollectionModel : ObservableCollection<TestModel>, INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public CollectionModel()
            {
                CollectionChanged += MyCollection_CollectionChanged;
            }          

            private void MyCollection_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
            {   // to notify XAML-side binding
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(TopCollection)));
            }
            public IEnumerable<TestModel> TopCollection => this.Take(10);
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CM.Add(new TestModel() {ABC= Guid.NewGuid().ToString() });
        }
    }
}
```

I clicked the button. However, the `CM` add new items successfully, but the UI did not update any.

Why it turns out to be this?

I used a breakpoint to test and found that the `CollectionChanged`&`OnPropertyChanged` all worked. But why the UI still did not update?
Would you please help me? Thank you.

Comment: Right now, you only set the ItemsSource once. But you need to update it after you updated the actual backing data.

Normally, this is done via `Bindings` (which you also use partially in your code above) ... and could theoretically be handled by either some attached property or some CollectionViewSource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind to the `TopCollection` property of the `CollectionModel` for the `PropertyChanged` event to have any effect:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = CM;
    IC.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("TopCollection"));
}
```

If you set the `DataContext` to the `CollectionModel` that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, you could do this in the XAML markup:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="IC" ItemsSource="{Binding TopCollection}" ... />
```

Comment: I tried and worked. Whereas, I need to bind the DataContext of the Window to the Window self so I can't bind it to the model. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Make CM a public *property* of the window and bind the `ItemsSource` to "CM.TopCollection".

Comment: Maybe I found my problem, I should bind the CM to the ItemsSource but not set it to the ItemsSource.

Comment: Yep, I changed the code like this:IC.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding { Source = CM }); and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your CollectionModel is an ObservableCollection, you got that much right. That means it will raise events (for subscribers to observe and act upon) when items are added/removed.

However, your "TopCollection", which you are actually binding to, is just an IEnumerable. In short, it doesn't raise the events that would make it fully data-binding.

You need to expose an ObservableCollection of your TopCollection. You could then raise events when its underlying data source changes, or even only when its filtered result changes.

Comment: However, even I replace the 'public IEnumerable<TestModel> TopCollection => this.Take(10);' to 'public ObservableCollection<TestModel> TopCollection => new ObservableCollection<TestModel>(this.Take(10));'. It still no works.

Comment: Yes, @mm8's change is also necessary.

Comment: Thanks all the same.